# Selecting by index inside a d3 selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm fairly new to d3 and struggling to find the answer to a specific problem I've been having. Below is the relevant code...

```
circles = base.selectAll("circle");

circles.attr("cx", function (d, i) {
            return +d3.select(this).attr("cx") + 2;
        })

circles.attr("cy", function (d, i) {
            return +d3.select(this).attr("cy") + 2;
        })
```

Where base.selectAll("circle") is selecting all svg circles previous generated with d3 in a different function.

The above works exactly as I want it to, my question is how would i replace the (this).attr() and replace is by selecting the index? For example if I wanted to select the circle before this within the function, something like the below but this obviously doesn't work.

```
+d3.select(d[i-1]).attr("cy")
```

Basically I want to loop within the function and compare (this).attr("cy") to all other selected positions. My code so far below

```
circles = base.selectAll("circle");

circles.attr("cx", function (d, i) {
    for (n = 0; n < circles.size(); n++) {
        if (n != i) {

            if (+d3.select(this).attr("cy") + +d3.select(this).attr("r") > +d3.select(d[n]).attr("cy") + +d3.select(d[n]).attr("r")) {
                 //do something
            }

        }
    }
})
```

where +d3.select(d[n]) isn't right. Any help would be greatly appreciated or just to be pointed in the right direction, no matter how I google this problem I just get pages of how d3.select work with other elements.

Comment: What do you *really* want to achieve? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There are possibly numerous solutions to this, many if not all prone to be off the track, though. *What* exactly do you want to select? *How many* circles do you want to select at a time? *What* are you going to do with this selection? Providing a [mcve] could be very helpful.

Comment: I'm going to be abandoning this approach and updating my code to ES6 so circle will have it's own class. I'm thinking I'm asking too much of d3 with approach and the object oriented approach will be far simpler in the long run

Comment: James, you **can** use D3 with an OOP approach, I'm not following your comment above. @altocumulus is probably right, this seems to be an XY problem, but still I wrote an answer talking about the less famous *third argument*, which can be useful to you.

Comment: James, that is exactly what I meant... it's all too vague, and now you are tossing in OO and ES6 without even clarifying what you are after. How are these concepts even related to your question? How should anyone be able to help you given the information you provided? @GerardoFurtado

Comment: Apologies for the vague comment, I essentially wanted to hold the question briefly as my code was being reviewed and mostly rewritten by a colleague. Even with the new syntax that still answers my question so many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The second and third arguments combined

I believe that @altocumulus is correct in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44459536/using-d3s-selectall-and-then-selecting-single-element-within-select-all-based-o#comment75916359_44459536) by saying that this is probably a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

However, I want to write an answer (for future users) because this has been asked many, many times, in different flavours:

> Inside a selection, how can I select the next element? How can I select two elements before? How can I select five elements ahead?

You can do this by combining the second and third arguments in the anonymous function:

```
.attr("foo", function(d, i, n){
//second and third ------^--^
```

Here comes an **important information**: `this`, the current element, is the same of `n[i]`.

Therefore, since `n[i]` is `this` (that is, the current element), you can simply use different indices to get different elements. For instance:

- `n[i-1]` → get the previous element
- `n[i+1]` → get the next element
- `n[i+4]` → get the element 4 positions ahead

... and so on.

#### Demo

Here is a very simple demo showing it. In the demo, I'm moving each circle to the position of the next one, which is calculated using:

```
.attr("cx", function(d, i, n) {
    return +d3.select(n[i + 1]).attr("cx")
})
```

Of course, you have so set a special rule for the last element, because there is no `n[i+1]` at that point (check the ternary operator).

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [140, 200, 30, 70, 270, 100, 220, 80];
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
    return 12 + 25 * i;
  })
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("fill", "tan")
  .attr("stroke", "dimgray")
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .delay(function(d, i) {
    return 1000 + i * 1000
  })
  .attr("cx", function(d, i, n) {
    return n[i + 1] ? +d3.select(n[i + 1]).attr("cx") : +d3.select(n[i]).attr("cx")
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="200"></svg>
```